# Creating a shaded/imprinted effect in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, shadows

[image: Adobe Illustrator indentation/impression shaded/lit effect]

I've been trying to work out how to create a similar indentation effect in Illustrator. I'm fine with creating the shapes, rotating them around a circle (Rotate > 360/12 > copy)...

...but I'm struggling with creating the illusion of depth.

I've been experimenting with drop shadow, strokes, opacity and bevel/extrude but am missing the right combination of effects to replicate this light highlighting and dark shadowing. What are the tool options for this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shadows

Menu Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel

[image: Shadows]

## Highlights

Menu Effect > Stylize > Drop Shadow

[image: Highlights]

## Result

[image: End]

Comment: Thank you! That looks great. I did play around with both Extrude and Bevel and Drop Shadow but evidently failed to combine them correctly! :)